# I am looking for ways to send emails efficiently

Tags: technology, efficiency, office

I have a standard email to reply to all enquiries from my website, however I need everytime to edit few words, such as the name of the person, dates, codes, etc.
Do you know a way of doing this fast and efficiently?(preferably for mac users)

Comment: Software reccommendations are off-topic here. I'm pretty sure something like this has been asked on the [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), please look around there.

Answer (score 2):

I would put the text of the email into a simple text editing program. But rather than putting in specific names, dates, codes, etc., I would include placeholder text such as

- [name]
- [date]
- [code1]
- [code2]

Then, in order to send an email reply to a person, I would do the following:

- Open up the file.
- Search for [name] and replace with the person's name.
- Search for [date] and replace that with the correct date.
- Do this for each of the placeholder fields.
- At the end, to make sure I didn't miss any of the placeholders, I'd search for the string "[", since that starts every placeholder.  If there was one I'd missed, I would replace it with the right text.
- Finally, I'd Select All, copy the text, paste it into the body of the reply email, and send it.

DON'T save the file after you've made changes. You need to keep them as placeholders so you can personalize it for the next website visitor!

Comment: Great answer. In this sort of situation, I always SAVE the file with a new name BEFORE I edit any of the tags, then if I accidentally save it, I still have the original intact.

Comment: @Lefty Smart! I usually save 2 copies of the original file, so if I accidentally save over one of them, I can restore it from the backup. And when I'm feeling particular smart, I also set the file properties of the original so it's "read only", so I _can't_ accidentally save over it.

Comment: You can't have too many copies - but for my way of working, I find it nice and easy to just open the file then immediately do ctrl-A and give it a new name before I start my changes.